# Response.Flush - OnFlush event in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, event-handling, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the domain names on web pages served by a DLL that I have no way to change.
I thought if there were events like OnFlush before Response.Flush occurs on the page I could do it all before the page is displayed. Is there a way to do this in ASP?

Thanks for your help.

P.S.: Something like Script_OnFlush in this APACHE extension: http://www.apache-asp.org/events.html

---

Following Nick's suggestion I have created a class that inherits from the Stream class.
Response.Filter is using this class to work on the HTML content...

By overriding the Write method I managed to rewrite the domain names on the site.

```
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) 
    {
     byte [ ] data = new byte [ count ];
    Buffer.BlockCopy ( buffer, offset, data, 0, count );

    string myHTML = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    string convertedHTML = myHTML.Replace("http://www.previousdomain.com", "http://www.currentdomain.com");

    data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(convertedHTML);

     _sink.Write ( data, 0, count );

    }
```

Thanks Nick!

Comment: Classic, I'm affraid. :(

Comment: Are these dlls ISAPI extensions, filters or COM components called from ASP pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can overload the R`esponse.Filter` property, which acts as a filter for all content that is returned to the browser.  You should do this in the `PostReleaseRequestState` in the `Global.asax`.

Comment: Isn't this about ASP? Eg. not asp.net but classic asp.

Comment: Nope, ASP.NET, if you don't want to use the Global.asax you can create your own module using IHttpModule interface.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but I need to do this somehow in classic ASP.

Comment: Oh then you are out of luck with anything built in.  You will need to write your own ISAPI provider, using C++.  Sorry Classic ASP is just a scripting language.  However if you were running this on IIS 7, you could use the integrated mode to code this in the same way I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'll check with IT about IIS 7.

Comment: You can also use a Reverse Proxy on the front end to deliver your site through ASP.NET if you are using IIS 6, sort of like I explained on my blog http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/02/url-rewriter-reverse-proxy-iis-wordpress/